# Internal Memory limit for tablet with no SD Card feature

Tags: android, memory, internal

I am developing an android app specifically for tablet. Which is essentially **an offline book reading app**. The app first **downloads the contents** of a particular book such as the book text, images in the book, and the audio/video files needed in the book. I am storing this book data into the **internal memory of the tablet, since most of the tablets do not have SD card functionality**. This download process is **done only once** for a particular book. Now there will be multiple books available for reading in the app, having the same functionality as above.

My concern is since all this data is stored in the internal memory, **what possible problems can my app face in terms of memory availability**. Now-a-days tablets come with internal memory starting with 8GB to 32GB. So even though I get internal memory in GBs will my app come across a memory low issue...

Another thing to share is my tablet will **only have the above app along with any other by default apps** provided by the manufacturer. So the internal memory will not be shared among many apps, leaving sufficient memory for my app execution..

I have this question only due to some tablets not having SD card feature, otherwise memory shortage was never a bothering problem..

Please if any one can guide me on this requirement of mine.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static File FileCache(Context context) {
        // Find the dir to save cached images
        File cacheDir;
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir = new File(
                    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "fileName");
        else
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
        return cacheDir;

}
```